# RestTemplate used for Http Outbound Gateway's is setting it's own header value instead of provided one

Tags: spring-integration

We are using Spring Integration 4 in our project and I am using `http:outbound-gateway` to hit a REST service. I am getting the following error when I run my code:

```
resulted in 400 (null)
```

Weirdly, what I observed is that the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` is setting request Accept header to `[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]` instead of my own header value for the header `Accept`. Why it is happening so and how to prevent this?

My outbound gateway:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway  url-expression="headers.restResourceUrl"
                                    http-method-expression="headers.httpMethod"
                                    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" >
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Here is the piece of the log file:

```
2018-01-24 17:42:10,089 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] setting headerName=[Accept], value=application/vnd.dsths.services-v8+xml
2018-01-24 17:42:10,089 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[sequencesize] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,089 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[originalpayload] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,090 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[httpmethod] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[authorization] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=authorization
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] setting headerName=[Authorization], value=Basic cmF2aV9rOnJhdmlAMTIzNA==
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[replychannel] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[businessarea] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[legacysystem] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[amisys-api-version] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[correlationid] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[id] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[content-type] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=content-type
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] setting headerName=[Content-Type], value=application/vnd.dsths.services-v8+xml
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[user-agent] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=user-agent
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] setting headerName=[user-agent], value=Java/1.6
2018-01-24 17:42:10,091 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[timestamp] WILL NOT be mapped
2018-01-24 17:42:10,128 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Created POST request for "http://10.166.120.97:9000/exetersoa/secured/rest/brokers/search/"
2018-01-24 17:42:10,133 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2018-01-24 17:42:10,135 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Writing [] as "application/vnd.dsths.services-v8+xml" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@19cc697c]
2018-01-24 17:42:10,840 DEBUG main [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] POST request for "http://10.166.120.97:9000/exetersoa/secured/rest/brokers/search/" resulted in 400 (null); invoking error handler
2018-01-24 17:42:10,846 DEBUG main [org.springframework.integration.router.HeaderValueRouter] org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://10.166.120.97:9000/exetersoa/secured/rest/brokers/search/]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
```

can anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

The `Accept` HTTP header is set in the `AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest()`:

```
if (this.responseType != null) {
        ...
            for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : getMessageConverters()) {
            ...
            }
            if (!allSupportedMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
                MediaType.sortBySpecificity(allSupportedMediaTypes);
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Setting request Accept header to " + allSupportedMediaTypes);
                }
                request.getHeaders().setAccept(allSupportedMediaTypes);
            }
        }
```

So, it iterates over configured `HttpMessageConverter`s and gather `allSupportedMediaTypes` independently of the value you provided before. And that's right behavior. You expect some object as a response and the `RestTemplate` must be able to convert to it. For this purpose it need to know which `Accept` type to allow for the server to build in response, so it will be able to find an appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` to build a reply object.

If you really are stick just with the `application/vnd.dsths.services-v8+xml`, you should reconfigure `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` via:

```
/**
 * Set a list of {@link HttpMessageConverter}s to be used by the underlying {@link RestTemplate}.
 * Converters configured via this method will override the default converters.
 * @param messageConverters The message converters.
 * @see RestTemplate#setMessageConverters(java.util.List)
 */
public void setMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
```

to only the converter for your specific `Accept` value. I guess that might be `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: We have used the same header value `application/vnd.dsths.services-v8+xml`  for `Accept`  in several other places i.e. in `http:outbound-gateway` components. But never faced this problem. Why all of a sudden now? Any guess please?

Comment: As I said: you have here `if (this.responseType != null) {`. I guess you just don't configure `expectedResponseType` there. That's not magic - just follow the code flow in the debugger!

Comment: Thanks for the response. My REST service needs three headers namely `Accept`, `Authorization`,`Content-Type` and I am setting values for them before hitting the REST service. But I am still unclear about why the `RestTemplate ` is ignoring them. BTW, I have added the `http:outbound-gateway` to the question. Please take a look now. Could you please clarify the things now?

Comment: ??? I told you already: you have there `expected-response-type="java.lang.String" `, so `RestTemplate` checks its `HttpMessageConverter`s who can deal with the response in the end for that expected type. And according their expectation it extracts their `MediaType` for the `Accept` header. That's how things work. Not sure what to explain you else. If you would like to enforce `RestTempalte` to work only with your expectations you should provide an appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` - `String` to `application/vnd.dsths.services-v8+xml` relationship.